# setup Apache to work with different ports for different web URLs

Tags: python, apache

I have SSL running on the server. https:[www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com), currently works for the website. However I want to have another domain https://mgmt.domainname.com, that I want a external user to connect to an python API from outside. The /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf has this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domaionname.com
            DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
            ServerName www.domaionname.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domaionname.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domaionname.com.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

How to set up Apache Virtualhost so that when a request comes via https://mgmt.domainname.com, I want to redirect it to port 8000 and access an internal Python program.